# How to add text in different position on multiple circle?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I drawn multiple circle in latex using the following code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (1cm) [radius=0.1] node {$T_1$}
circle (0.6cm) 
circle (0.2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But, I want add text as shown in the following image as[image: circle-text]

Please guide me as how to add text as per in the image.. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**: You are already loading the `positioning` library. In order to be sure that the texts fit, you may want to draw the circles consecutively. This answer comes with a style

```
concentric fit={with center <center node> and nodes {<list of nodes>}}
```

this allows you to conveniently fit all texts in a circle node whose center coincides with the one of the `center node`. If you also load `backgrounds`, you can shade the circle without wiping out the texts.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,shadings,backgrounds,calc}
\pgfkeys{tikz/.cd,
maximal concentric radius/.store in=\MaxConcRad,
maximal concentric radius=0,
get maximal distance/.code n args={3}{\foreach \X in {south west,south east,north west,north east}
{\path let \p1=($(#2.center)-(#3.\X)$),\n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)} in 
\pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{#1}{max(#1,abs(\n1))}
\xdef#1{#1}}; }},
center node/.store in=\CenterNode,
get maximal distance from center/.code={\foreach \X in {south west,south east,north west,north east}
{\path let \p1=($(\CenterNode.center)-(#1.\X)$),\n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)} in 
\pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\MaxConcRad}{max(\MaxConcRad,abs(\n1))}
\xdef\MaxConcRad{\MaxConcRad}}; }
},
concentric fit/.style args={with center #1 and nodes #2}{%
center node=#1,get maximal distance from center/.list=#2,
minimum size=2*\MaxConcRad*1pt,
at={(#1.center)}
}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
\node[circle,draw,inner sep=1pt] (T1) at (1,1) {fff};
\node[above=1pt of T1] (eee) {eee};
\node[circle,draw,concentric fit={with center T1 and nodes {eee}}] (bigger circle){};
\node[above=1pt of bigger circle] (aaa) {aaa};
\node[below=1pt of bigger circle] (ccc) {ccc};
\node[left=1pt of bigger circle] (bbb) {bbb};
\node[right=1pt of bigger circle] (ddd) {ddd};
\node[circle,draw,concentric fit={with center T1 and nodes {{aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd}}},
path picture={\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\shade[upper left=blue!20, lower right=blue!40] 
(0,0) circle (\MaxConcRad*1pt);
\end{scope}}] (big circle){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,shadings,backgrounds,fit,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,inner sep=1pt]
\node[circle,draw,inner sep=1pt] (T1) {$T_1$};
\node[above=1pt of T1] (eee) {eee};
\node[below=1pt of T1,opacity=0] (eee-cheat) {eee};
\node[circle,draw,fit=(eee) (eee-cheat)] (bigger circle) {};
\node[above=1pt of bigger circle] (aaa) {aaa};
\node[below=1pt of bigger circle] (ccc) {ccc};
\node[left=1pt of bigger circle] (bbb) {bbb};
\node[right=1pt of bigger circle] (ddd) {ddd};
\node[circle,draw,fit=(aaa) (bbb) (ccc) (ddd)] (big circle) {};
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\shade[upper left=blue!20, lower right=blue!40]
let \p1=($(big circle.north)-(big circle.center)$) in
(big circle.center) circle (\y1);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is slighlty different in that you are adding circles around the text as opposed to adding the text within the _given_ circles. Still a valid soluton though.

Comment: @PeterGrill Yes, that's why it's good there are two answers, but I had already upvoted yours. ;-) (I'll now try to do some `concentric fit` style,,,,)

Answer (score 2):

You can place nodes with approriate `shifts` and `anchors`:

[image]

### Notes:

- The `bbb` and `ddd` text doesn't quite fit (without scaling, thus the `font=\tiny`).  I modiited the `inner sep=0pt` of these two so that the separation between the text and its bounding box is set to `0pt`.
- The `xshift` and `yshift` are form the center of the circle and the `anchor` controls which point on the virtual box around the text is positioned at the specified location.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tiny]
\draw (0,0) [fill=cyan!30]
    circle  (1cm)   
        node {fff}
        node [yshift=1cm, anchor=north] {aaa}
        node [xshift=1cm, anchor=east, inner sep=0pt] {bbb}
        node [xshift=-1cm, anchor=west, inner sep=0pt] {ddd}
        node [yshift=-1cm, anchor=south] {ccc}
    circle (0.6cm) 
        node [yshift=0.6cm, anchor=north] {eee} 
    circle (0.2cm)
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much to all[J Leon V., marmot, Peter Grill ] .. exactly this one I expect.. Thanks..

Comment: Also guide me as; how to add the caption (Fig. Name ) of tikz picture at top/bottom of the image?

Comment: @user1999109: As that is totally unrelated to positioning text, that should be a separate question. There should already be answer on this site regarding captioning.

Answer (score 2):

An option with basic tikz code.

RESULT:
[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
%\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} % Set font to serif family | affect entire document.
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        %Environment config
        font=\sffamily, %Best way to write in serif, only afects environment. | credit to @marmot's answer.
        %Environment styles
        Circle/.style={
            circle,
            draw,
            minimum width=#1,
            left color=blue!5,
            right color=blue!80!cyan!25,
            shading angle=45
        }
    ]

    \node[Circle=3.8cm](C) at (0,0){};
    \node[
        Circle=2.3cm,
        label=0:bbb,
        label=90:aaa,
        label=180:ddd,
        label=270:ccc
    ](C) at (0,0){};
    \node[
        Circle,%Radious controled by node text width
        label=-30:fff,
        label=90:eee,
        label=-120:ggg,
    ](C) at (0,0){$\mathsf{T_1}$}; %node text in math serif
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: ok.. Thank you very much to all.. I will check already asked question regarding captioning.. thanks..